# Class property set removing part of a string

Tags: php, string, class, properties

I have this function to fill my class vars. When there is a file to handle, `handle_uploaded_files()` is called that return a comma separated file list name.

When i access the `$this->image` the values are corrects (`"image(1).jpg,image(2).jpg,image(3).jpg,image(4).jpg"`), but when access the property outside the class, i receive a strange result: only commas, but no values between then (`",,,"`).

```
public function fill_vars($array, $files = null) {
    foreach(array_keys($array) as $key => $value) {
        $this->$value = $array[$value];
        if (!empty($files)) {
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = handle_uploaded_files($files[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's going on. Any advices?

*Sorry about my english.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your variables in the inner `foreach`-loop. You overwrite `$key` and `$value` from the outer loop.

There is no point in calling `array_keys($array)` in the outer loop since $key becomes a numeric index of the key in the newly generated array. Instead you can write

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $this->$key = $value;
    /* ... */
}
```

This only works if `$key` is a valid identifier. But that's no different than your code.

The inner loop can be rewritten as

```
$this->$key = handle_uploaded_files($value);
```

But you definitely should rename inner loop variables first.

After that you can check if `$this->$key` from the inner loop should ever overwrite `$this->$key` from the outer loop.

Comment: your answer was perfect. I'm felling a little dumb now, but this kind of thing happens. And i didn't needed to change my inner foreach vars, i just need to move the second loop to outside of the first. Thanks, man!